# Add entries in bulk

Tags: entries, structure, import

Is there a way to add a whole bunch of entries at once? For example, I have a parent entry in a Structure section, and want to add a bunch of children, just setting the title on each one real quick.

I could write a plugin to do it, but wanted to see if something was already out there first.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, a plugin is the way to go.  There are a [couple](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/import) of Craft [importing](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/ee-craft-import) plugins that might get you where you want to go.

Long-term, we've got some plans around importing and exporting data from a Craft install as well, but no ETA on it.